# differences between LSQR and FTRL when working with very sparse data

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent, online-learning

I have a 2M instances dataset with millions of very very sparse dummy variables created using the `hashing trick` = `hash(orig_feature_name + orig_feature_value)=1`. Note that the data is sparse both on rows (every instance has only a limited <100 features=1) and on columns (most features are relevant only to very few instances < 1%)

I discovered that in such sparse scenarios the `follow-the-regularized-leader FTRL proximal gradient descent` is very popular:
[paper](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/papers/ad-click-prediction.pdf), [reference implementation](https://github.com/mlandry22/kaggle/blob/master/modern_logistic_regression/fast_solution_v3.py).

But I'm not sure why shouldn't I prefer a `batch` gradient descent algorithm? FTRL for all its merits is still an `online-learning` algorithm that sees one instance at a time.

So what are the advantages and disadvantages of using FTRL vs. a well known sparse least squares algorithm such as `LSQR` ([paper](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme324/paige-saunders2.pdf), [reference implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lsqr.py))?

My intuition is that if possible to use all the data for each iteration, we should do it, but I'm not sure...